# javascript could not find the tr element

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

I visited a private website, and I want to retrieve the content of a `tr` element. However, `document.querySelector("tr")` cannot obtain the content even though I cached the page and confirmed that the tr element exists by opening the text file. Furthermore, even when I opened the cached page in the browser, I still couldn't get the result. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the HTML text contains incomplete or invalid tags, the parsing process may fail to query the `tr` element.

for example

```js
// missing table
const inValidHTML = `
<tr><td>Row 1, Column 1</td><td>Row 1, Column 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 2, Column 1</td><td>Row 2, Column 2</td></tr>
`

// ok
const validHTML = `<table>
<tr><td>Row 1, Column 1</td><td>Row 1, Column 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 2, Column 1</td><td>Row 2, Column 2</td></tr>
</table>
`

// ok. change tr to "mytr"
const validHTML2 = `
<mytr><td>Row 1, Column 1</td><td>Row 1, Column 2</td></mytr>
<mytr><td>Row 2, Column 1</td><td>Row 2, Column 2</td></mytr>
`

const parser = new DOMParser()
const doc = parser.parseFromString(inValidHTML, 'text/html')
const trElements = doc.querySelectorAll('tr')
console.log(trElements.length) // 0

console.log(parser.parseFromString(validHTML, 'text/html').querySelectorAll('tr').length) // 2
console.log(parser.parseFromString(validHTML2, 'text/html').querySelectorAll('mytr').length) // 2
```